# Groovy stoppable commands chain

Tags: groovy, dsl

Is it possible in groovy to create a command chain that would not be fully executed?
For example:

```
when(booleanVar).then(returnExpression)
```

If the booleanVar is false, I don't want the returnExpression to be executed at all, because it may be a method call to some external service, so I only want to execute it if necessary. So I want the "when" method to be able to control if the rest of the chain should be executed.
I want to use it in a DSL, so it'd be used like this:

```
when booleanVar then returnExpression
```

I'd rather avoid using closures, cause the syntax then would be less readable.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using AST Transformation to change the invocation:

```
when(booleanVar).then(returnExpression)
```

to this:

```
when({booleanVar}).then({returnExpression})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the when() translated false to null, you could use the [safe navigation operator](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_safe_navigation_operator) like this, but I don't think it lends itself to easy reading in a DSL once you strip the parentheses--not even sure if it would work correctly without them. But it's a possibility.

```
when(booleanVar)?.then(returnExpression)
```